# Facebook api swift current user is nil

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with Facebook api. After login and success unwrapping user token I have a problem with taking user profile: it's nil.

```
func updateLoginStatus() {
    if let _ = AccessToken.current {
        let currentUser = UserProfile.current
        userName.text = currentUser?.fullName
        userPictureView = UserProfile.PictureView(frame: blankUserImage.frame, profile: currentUser)
        userPictureView!.clipsToBounds = true
        userPictureView!.layer.cornerRadius = userPictureView!.bounds.width/2
        popUpView.addSubview(userPictureView!)
        isLogged = true
        updateLabels()
    } else {
        isLogged = false
        userPictureView?.removeFromSuperview()
        updateLabels()
    }
}
```

Even if I try to get profile manual by using `let userProfile = UserProfile(userId: (AccessToken.current?.userId)!)` it also take nil at all parameters, but it have initialized user. Funny part is that with that UserProfile.current it have take user picture. What it can be? How I can get full user name by other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem happend in android too.
You should load profile (listen profile change in android) after you got access token.
I write a sample and just tested in swift 3, Facebook iOS SDK 4.21.0.
Then you can got updatedUser.

```
if let _ = FBSDKAccessToken.current() {
    if let currentUser = FBSDKProfile.current() {
        print("current user got: \(currentUser)")
    } else {
        print("current user not got")
        FBSDKProfile.loadCurrentProfile(completion: {
            profile, error in
            if let updatedUser = profile {
                print("finally got user: \(updatedUser)")
            } else {
                print("current user still not got")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How I understand, after getting AccessToken UserProfile.current must be automate updated, but it does not happened?

Comment: The document is not written clearly. Only that can be obtained after login.